# Conversion error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

In my SQL query:

```
  insert into Tbl_EmpMovement_T values (
        '004101',
        '2011-8-26',
        CONVERT(datetime,convert(varchar(10),'2011-8-26',120)+' ' +
        CONVERT(varchar(2),SUBSTRING('8:16',1,2))+':'+
        convert(varchar(2),SUBSTRING('8:16',4,2))+':00.000',120),
        CONVERT(datetime,convert(varchar(10),'2011-8-26',120)+' ' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(2),SUBSTRING('6:02',1,2))+':'+  
        convert(varchar(2),SUBSTRING('6:02',4,2))+':00.000',120)
  )
```

I am getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather try this:

```
         insert into Tbl_EmpMovement_T values (
        '004101',
        '2011-8-26',
        CAST ('2011-8-26' + ' ' +
   (  SUBSTRING('16:02',0, PATINDEX('%:%', '16:02')+1)) + 
    ( SUBSTRING('16:02',PATINDEX('%:%', '16:02')+1, 2)) AS datetime),
         CAST ('2011-8-26' + ' ' +
   (  SUBSTRING('16:02',0, PATINDEX('%:%', '16:02')+1)) + 
    ( SUBSTRING('16:02',PATINDEX('%:%', '16:02')+1, 2)) AS datetime)
  )
```

This way, you wont have a problem when the time part moves between single and double digit hours.

Comment: Again the question is why all these substrings?!

Comment: I completely agree, surely CAST('some date as string' as datetime) might be easier, but it could be that the OP wants to add date, hour and minute from 3 different sources together as one datetime. I also await the answer to your question...